Why rough path theory principle is not applied in parameter estimation of stochastic differential equation(SDE)?
My apologies if this question is not proper for this site, but I could not figure out the following. Can anyone provide insight? It is almost certain that stochastic differential equations (SDEs) can be used to model noise in quantum computation, and that it might be possible to maintain coherence by controlling the environment through proper estimation of the SDE parameters. In this context, many methods must have been used to estimate these parameters. However, since rough path theory provides path wise convergence under many circumstances, methods based on rough path theory should theoretically be better than other approaches for parameter estimation. In other words the signatures of rough path can be helpful to model the noise and the parameter to maintain coherence. Why has no one worked on this? Why are there no references addressing this issue?
Or I am not searching the web properly. Any comment?
EDIT: The following link shows and SDE applicable. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2405.14283

can you include some references for the type of SDE systems that you have in mind?

@ThomasKojar I have added a link for a reference. Can we use tough path theory for the SDE mentioned?

In the book "a course on rough paths" Chapter 9 Stochastic differential equations Theorem 9.1, they go over the pathwise lift for SDE solutions. The regularity there for the volatility is C3_b, so I am not sure if that is useful in your context.

@ThomasKojar Thank you for your comment. I understand volatility can be a limitation.  Considering allowable volatility, I was expecting to see  work related to extending application of rough path to Non-Markovian settings.

yes for example the fractional Brownian motion is not Markov and one can use Rough paths for it e.g. see here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351549/rough-paths-theory-for-non-markovian-processes. The Rough paths are really a deterministic construction i.e. it doesn't use martingale/Markov structure. In that book they also do the construction for very general Gaussian processes. Also check out the Friz-Victoir book https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~friz/master4_May6th.pdf Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as
Rough Paths: Theory and Applications

Yes. Are these references related to application in quantum computation? I will look soon.

these are some of the main references for rough paths theory.  I am not sure which particular SDE you have in mind, maybe include it in your post. In the article you mentioned they mention a bunch of them For example, the (18) is a backward SDE and that might also fall inside RDEs depending on the regularity of that $p_t$ function.

@ThomasKojar, Yes, equation 18 can be a starting point. I was wondering if the gradient term $∇_xlogp_t (x(t))$ could benefit from rough path theory's extension to high-order iterated integrals. In addition, the reverse-time noise process ($W(T)$) could be generalized to a rough path to handle non-Markovian environment? May I ask for your views?

A nice very similar context of studying reverse-time SDEs using rough paths is in the work "Generative Fractional Diffusion Models" https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.17638v2. Here they have to deal with a non-Markovian setting too as in your equation (18).

Thank you for the reference. I will have a look. Have you found anything related to quantum computation?

No I didn't search. I was mostly searching for the particular SDE you are interested in.

No worries. I searched a lot, but never found one. I was wondering if it is possible to write a  paper in that area.  May  I ask your view?

sounds very interesting.  If you encounter any specific technical difficulties, feel free to post them on Mathoverflow.
